Why do I get "no such table: <tablename>"?
I would like to implement an SQLite database in my Expo application. While following the official documentation I encountered this error:
→ Caused by: Error code: no such table: <tablename>]
 ERROR [Error: Call to function 'NativeDatabase.prepareAsync' has been rejected.

So I modified my code, which solved the problem at first:
import { Suspense, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";
import { SQLiteProvider } from "expo-sqlite";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

export default function RootLayout() {
  const configDatabase = async () => {
    const dbName = "database.db";
    const dbAsset = require("../assets/data/database.db");
    const dbUri = Asset.fromModule(dbAsset).uri;
    const dbFilePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/${dbName}`;

    const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dbFilePath);

    if (!fileInfo.exists) {
      await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/`,
        // eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
        { intermediates: true }
      );
      await FileSystem.downloadAsync(dbUri, dbFilePath);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDatabase = async () => {
      try {
        await configDatabase();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
    fetchDatabase();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <SQLiteProvider databaseName="database.db" useSuspense={true}>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="index"
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </Stack>
      </SQLiteProvider>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

After a while the error occurred again. I then tried my basic code, but the error remained:
export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <SQLiteProvider
        databaseName="database.db"
        useSuspense={true}
        assetSource={{ assetId: require("../assets/data/database.db") }}
      >
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="index"
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </Stack>
      </SQLiteProvider>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

I only updated my emulator on Android Studio. After that I updated my packages, but the error is still there, even on my Android phone.
package.json:
"dependencies": {
  "@expo-google-fonts/changa": "^0.2.3",
  "@expo-google-fonts/kanit": "^0.2.3",
  "@expo-google-fonts/maven-pro": "^0.2.3",
  "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
  "expo": "~51.0.17",
  "expo-asset": "~10.0.10",
  "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
  "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
  "expo-font": "~12.0.7",
  "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
  "expo-router": "~3.5.17",
  "expo-sqlite": "~14.0.4",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.74.2",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
  "react-native-screens": "3.31.1"
},


Did you actually try to find a table called <tablename>? If not, does the table exist?

I forgot to mention that this code was working fine a few days ago: I haven't modified the project structure in the meantime. If I modify the structure, I get an error telling me that the path to my database is incorrect.
In my case, my table is called 'category' and I can see its data without any problem in VSCode. After that, I also tried deleting my database and creating it again with some data, but the error is still there.

I found this post during my research: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/27748
I may have misinterpreted it, but it gave me an idea. So I solved my problem by modifying the configDatabase function in this way:
  const configDatabase = async () => {
    const dbName = "database.db";
    const dbAsset = require("../assets/data/database.db");
    const dbUri = Asset.fromModule(dbAsset).uri;
    const dbFilePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/${dbName}`;

    try {
      const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dbFilePath);

      if (fileInfo.exists) {
        await FileSystem.deleteAsync(dbFilePath);
      }

      await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/`,
        { intermediates: true }
      );

      await FileSystem.downloadAsync(dbUri, dbFilePath);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

Now I'll have to see if this solves my problem for good.
I would like to point out that my project's database is created via a python script, so when I run my React Native code with Expo, the database is already present, so this may have an influence.

Thnx! Was searching for hours on this.

I just started again my app and I'm getting again the same error :/ Didn't change my code whatsoever in between while it was working. Calling the 'prepareAsync' function has failed → Caused by: Error code 1: no such table: XXX
